# Facebook share button not updating image

Tags: facebook

I'm building a custom app where you can build a jacket by choosing different options, then the image updates to reflect what you chose. When you're done, you can share the jacket you built on facebook.  The challenge I'm having is that when get to the share button, facebook doesn't want to pull the right image. You have to click the share button, then cancel three times or so before it pulls the right image. Any idea why?

Here's where it gets a bit complicated. The image is generated by a script that merges all the options you chose into a single image. The facebook og:image property points to the image merging script. It works perfectly in the the facebook developer tools, but when it's not forced to rescrape the image through the developer tool it doesn't pull the image the first time. I'm even trying to add `<?php echo(microtime());?>` to the query so it sees a new url each time. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here's the facebook metadata for the page.

```
<!--facebook meta-->  
<meta property="og:image" content="http://charlesanconaequestrian.com/process/mergePhotos.php?<?php echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];?>&mt=<?php echo(microtime());?>" />  
<meta property="og:title" content="Charles Ancona | Custom Equestrian Jackets"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100005487631132" />
<meta property="og:type"   content="website" />  
<meta property="og:url"    content="http://charlesanconaequestrian.com/design/checkout.php?<?php echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];?>&mt=<?php echo(microtime());?>" /> 
<meta property="og:description"    content="Look at the awesome jacket I just built!!!" />
```

If it's helpful to see the website, go to [http://www.charlesanconaequestrian.com/design](http://www.charlesanconaequestrian.com/design/) and click on a few options. Then at the end, click the "share" button, then the facebook share button on the new page.  It'll eventually work, but you have to click the facebook sharer button a bunch of times first.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to see what Graph is actually finding.  And because it always chaches stuff, it's not always easy.  Use this tool (with your URL already included)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://charlesanconaequestrian.com/process/mergePhotos.php

In your case, it looks like you are setting the og:image to a PHP result.  That won't work.  You need to actually set it to the image you want to show.  Which can be done dynamically as you are attempting.  Just use the above tool to test it, and force it to re-scrape the data.

Comment: Of course you can use a script for your `og:image`, as long as it outputs correct image data and Content-Type header.

Comment: That's part of the problem. When I force it to rescrape the image it works perfectly every time. However, when I'm outside of the developer tools it has trouble pulling the right image the first time. It's most certainly a caching problem.

Comment: As long as your URL is different every time, you shouldn't have a caching issue.  Perhaps, throw a random number on to the end of the location string, or something.  I've actually done this before, and it prevents caching.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that's what the code <?php echo(microtime());?> does. Still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Huh.  Ok...  Are you sure that the meta tags are on the right page?  And they are receiving all the correct information?  Because if all that PHP stuff doesn't get generated, and it's all left blank, that would explain your chaching problem.